# Stacked columnrange and scatter chart alignment issue

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvot15xf/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
$(function() {

$('#container').highcharts({
/*
    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange'
    },*/
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
      /*  plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 3
            }
        },*/
    series: [{
      name: 'Temperatures',
      data: [
        [0,-9.7, 9.4],
        [1,-9.7, 6.5],
        [2,-3.5, 9.4],
        [3,-1.4, 19.9],
        [4,0.0, 22.6],
        [5,2.9, 29.5],
        [6,9.2, 30.7],
        [7,7.3, 26.5],
        [8,4.4, 18.0],
        [9,-3.1, 11.4],
        [10,-5.2, 10.4],
        [11,-13.5, 9.8]
      ],
      pointWidth: 0,
        type:'columnrange',

      }, {
      name: 'Min-Temperatures',
      type: 'scatter',
      //data: [-9.7,-8.7,-3.5,-1.4,0.0, 2.9, 9.2, 7.3, 4.4, -3.1,-5.2,-13.5],
      data: [
        [0, -9.7],
        [1, -9.7],
        [2, -3.5],
        [3, -1.4],
        [4, 0.0],
        [5, 2.9],
        [6, 9.2],
        [7, 7.3],
        [8, 4.4],
        [9, -3.1],
        [10, -5.2],
        [11, -13.5]
      ]

    }]

  });

});
```

With the fiddle here, I am trying to create a columnrange chart with the lowest point being the scatter chart. Somehow the scatter chart point does not want to get aligned with the columnrange chart, it is slightly left aligned.

I have tried to play with the pointWidth property but it doesn't give a consistent result.

Is there some other property that I might be missing here to bring both the graphs in horizontal alignment.

Comment: Fiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvot15xf

Comment: `pointWidth: 0` doesn't sound properly. Setting it to `3` works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvot15xf/2/

Comment: This property `pointWidth` has different behavior in different browsers/systems. The graphs are aligned with `pointWidth :3` in one browser but not another. I was wondering if there is some additional property that can stack the `scatter` circle point right under `columnrange` vertical line.

Comment: I see. Check this [ticket](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3002) - it looks like exactly the same issue.